# How to write clean, readable ReactJS Components with conditional renders?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-frontend

The result is not showing in my window. I have created a global object for testing:

```js
const obj = {
  onam: [
    {
      name: "name3",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "name2",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg"
    }
  ],
  christmas: [
    {
      name: "name1",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "name0",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the function I am calling inside render.

```
const grid = (props) => {
  if (props == "All") {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    // looping through keys
    keys.forEach((key, index) => { 
      // looping through array in keys
      for(let j = 0; j < Object.keys(obj).length; j++) {
        return (
          <div>
            <a><img src={obj[key][j].image}>{obj[key][j].name}</img></a>
          </div>
        )
      }
    });   
  }
}
```

I know there is some error in the above function but I cant sort it out. I am calling `{grid("All")}` inside render. My aim is to display a div containing a div with all images with a tag. I would like to learn a clean way of conditionally rendering my components.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to fix here. You mention using `this.state.current_nav` but functional components don't access state that way. Please update your question with the error you're getting.

Comment: I did the necessary edit ,still i a begineer in react and i am keep forgetting some important syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several concerns here Ashwin.

- Your component name should begin with uppercase.
- Use an array instead of object `obj`. Its easier to work with arrays and loop through them than it is to loop objects.
- Don't wrap the entire component within an if statement. Its bad practice.
- `props == "All"` is just wrong. props is an object not a string. This is the main reason nothing is rendering. That if statement will always return false.
- `<img>` doesn't take children so don't pass `{obj[key][j].name}` into the img tag. Move that bit after the closing img tag into the `<a>` tag.

I'm rewriting your component with some comments to help you learn, but there are several other ways to achieve the same result, perhaps with a better approach. This works for me and I find it's more readable and easier to understand.

```
import React from "react"

/* An array of objects is always easier to work than objects with 
multiple arrays as values. You might end up duplicating a few keys like
"festival" in this example, but it will make your life easier.
 */

const arr = [
    {
      festival: "oman",
      name: "name3",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg",
    },
    {
      festival: "oman",
      name: "name2",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg",
    },
    {
      festival: "christmas",
      name: "name1",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg",
    },
    {
      festival: "christmas",
      name: "name0",
      image: "https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_828/gif/kelp-biofuel.jpg",
    },
]

/* 
Always make sure your components are uppercase

De-structure your props with { propName1, propName2 }
because that way you or anybody else looking at your
component immediately can recognize what props are being
passed.
*/
const Grid = ({ whatToRender }) => {
  /*  
  Create a custom render function inside your component if
  you need to render conditionally. Its easier to work with
  debug and maintain. 
  */
  const renderGrid = () => {
    if (whatToRender === "all") { // use === over == because that will check for type equality as well.
      return arr.map((item) => ( // () is equivalent to return () when looping.
        /* Always pass a unique key if you are creating lists or lopping */
        <div key={item.image}> 
          <a>
            <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
            {item.name}
          </a>
        </div>
      ))
    }
    if (whatToRender === "onam") {
      return arr.map((item) => {
        if (item.festival === "onam") {
          return (
            <div key={item.image}>
              <a>
                <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                {item.name}
              </a>
            </div>
          )
        }
      })
    }
    if (whatToRender === "christmas") {
      return arr.map((item) => {
        if (item.festival === "christmas") {
          return (
            <div key={item.image}>
              <a> {/* Image tags don't take children they are self-closing */}
                <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                {item.name}
              </a>
            </div>
          )
        }
      })
    } // Return an empty div if none of the cases pass. So, you return valid JSX
    return <div></div>
  }
  return renderGrid() // Finally return your custom render function
}

export default Grid
```

**EDIT**

On visiting this question again, I realized that there was a better way to write it. A much shorter version. It uses the same arr defined in the above code sample.

```
const Grid = ({ whatToRender }) => {
  const renderGrid = () => {
    return arr.map((item) => {
      if (item.festival === whatToRender || whatToRender === "all") {
        return (
          <div key={item.image}>
            <a>
              <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
              {item.name}
            </a>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
  }
  return renderGrid()
}

export default Grid
```

Which one to use? The second version not only because it's much shorter, but also because its reusable. If in the future you add another festival to `arr` say Easter, you just need changes in the array and the prop value you are passing. The component will require no changes.

Comment: i am actually amazed at your typing speed ,you wrote the entire component as it was  a peice of cake

Comment: How didi you develop somethong like that ,any suggession for me?(i spend a full day and got nowhere)

Comment: I'm slow compared to most people answering on Stack Overflow. Don't worry. It takes time, effort & practice. It'll come to you as well, just don't give up. Learn from the right sources. 

https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/ -> This is a very good source. Wait for a good offer. Udemy gives it away for as little as Rs. 450 or less.

 If you want a free source. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFaFIcGhPoM&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwgg3vaYJgHGnModB54rxOk3&ab_channel=Codevolution -> He is also very good. Practice with them. You'll get better in no time. All the best. :D

Comment: @AshwinJoshy `any suggession for me?` -> Check out some videos and articles on VSCode keyboard shortcuts, useful extensions and even using typescript. A good IDE setup can make you a whole lot more productive, especially in writing repetitive code.